# Access private variable in global scope

Tags: c++, scope, global-scope

In this below code, the foo function in the global scope tries to access the private variables of a Box, which ofcourse doesn't work. I have to make the foo function work with one line of code at the place show code for a school assignment.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Box {
      int x,y;

      public:
             Box(int xi,int yi) {x=xi;y=yi;}
             // One line of code to make foo(Box, Box) work
};

bool foo(Box l,Box r) {return (l.x*l.y)>(r.x*r.y);}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Box b1(3,4),b2(1,2);

    if (foo(b1,b2)) cout << "b1>b2\n";

    return cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `foo` as a `friend function` inside `Box`

```
   #include<iostream>

   class Box {
     int x,y;

     public:
         Box(int xi,int yi) :x(xi),y(yi){}// Always use initializer list for initializing data members, i.e. prefer initialization over assignment

         friend bool foo(Box,Box);// friend functions can access private members
   };

   bool foo(Box l,Box r)       // friend keyword not to be written while defining the function
   {return (l.x*l.y)>(r.x*r.y);}

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      Box b1(3,4),b2(1,2);

      if (foo(b1,b2)) std::cout << "b1>b2\n";

     return std::cin.get();
   }
```

Comment: For questions tagged homework I think it's better to give the needed guidance without the exact code.  That way they can look into what you tell them and learn from it instead of copy/pasting.

Comment: @Brian: Yes I agree but this I think is not a valid reason for your downvote.

Comment: You're making an assumption, I didn't downvote.  Check my account number of downvotes.  I rarely downvote.  I like to leave comments instead.  Probably one of the people that pressed up on my comment.

Comment: @Brian: No hard feelings. I just thought only you have commented on my post so the downvote would most probably be yours.

Answer (score 9):

Look into the [friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/465sdshe(VS.80).aspx) keyword.

Answer (score 3):

First off, this is **not** a priori a dirty thing. The placement of the comment line already indicates that the class `Box` controls who is allowed to touch its privates (pun intended).

Secondly, since this is a school assignment I think that the solution should have been mentioned in class: this can be achieved using a `friend` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers involving friends, a better answer for the long term (although not a one-line change) would be for Box to overload the appropriate comparison operators.